# Laravel Submit Form Without Page Refresh Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to post the phone number in my modal popup form.but don't want to disappear the popup after submitting the form clicking on "continue" button. Here is my blade.php code.

```
            <div id="modal-wrapper" class="modal">
  
              <form class="modal-content animate" id="addform">
               
                               
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number" placeholder="01**********">
                  </div> 
                  </div>
                  
                <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;padding-left:18px;">
                  <button type="submit"  style="background-color: #a5abb0;" class="mobile-login__button">CONTINUE
                </button>
              </div>
```

here is my script part for ajax part of the code.

```
 <script>
                
                  $("#addform").on('submit',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
              
                    $.ajax({
                      type:"post"
                      url: "/client-mobile-login"
                      data: $("addform").serialize(),
                      success:function(response){
                        
                      },
                      error:function(error){
                        console.log(error)
                        alert("not send");
                      }
              
                      )};
                    });
                  
                });
              
                </script>
```

and here is my controller function

```
     public function client_mobile_login(Request $request)
      {
       $client_phone1='88'.$request->input('phone_number');
    
    $result=DB::table('client')
            ->where('client_phone1',$client_phone1)
            ->first();
           {{ here is my otp sending code.... }}

            if($result)
            {       
                   $request->session()->put('client_title', $result->client_title);
                   

               // print_r($client_phone1);
               }
```

Comment: Is the `<script>` part after the `<form>` part?

Answer (score 2):

Use **type=button**

```
<button type="button" id="submitForm" ...>CONTINUE</button>
```

And trigger your ajax on click event

```
$("#submitForm").on('click',function(e){ ... }
```

Comment: it prevents reload of the page.but query inside the controller is not working here,what to do?

Comment: What error do you get? Also, make sure to use _token in your post call.

Comment: i have used csrf token. when I click on 'continue' button ,nothing happens.the page remain as it is.no change .

Comment: Check your network console. Are you seeing a request being made? If yes, then on ajax success or error ... do something